# three.js renders unexpected color values using points and custom shading and blending

Tags: three.js, webgl, rendering

I have a relatively simple setup with **custom shader** and a **custom blend mode**:

- A `Scene` and a `PerspectiveCamera`
- An `IcosahedronBufferGeometry`
- A custom `new THREE.ShaderMaterial` with custom shaders
- Some `new THREE.Points` with the icosahedron and that custom shader material

My shader material has a custom blend mode:

```
shaderMaterial.blending =      THREE.CustomBlending;
shaderMaterial.blendSrc =      THREE.OneFactor;
shaderMaterial.blendDst =      THREE.OneFactor;
shaderMaterial.blendEquation = THREE.AddEquation;
```

and my fragment shader currently only does this:

`gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0);`

Since I'm rendering into a fully black canvas, the expected color of drawn points should be, considering the blending mode:

```
 SRC                     DST
r = 0                   r = 0                 r = 0
g = 0.1   *   1.0   +   g = 0   *   1.0   =   g = 0.1
b = 0                   b = 0                 b = 0
```

However, I get a totally different result:

[image: points on an icosahedron]

The points are rendered much more brightly than the expected `0.1`. Using
`gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0);`
the points become fully saturated `(g = 255)`.

What causes this? I have some ideas and hopefully can push me in the right direction.

1. Perhaps three.js appends some code to my fragment shader, modifying the `gl_FragColor`?
2. Maybe I'm not aware of some extra rendering / post processing step that three.js does?
3. Maybe I've misunderstood the math regarding blending modes?
4. Maybe there is some implementation error in three.js?
5. Perhaps it's a browser / canvas / color space thing? (However, I cannot imagine any transformation that causes a green value of 0.2 to become fully saturated (255) in any color space transformation!)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Is [`premultipliedAlpha`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.alpha) on or off?

Comment: Premultiplied alpha is not set (default = false) but to my knowledge that should not matter either way since it's a custom shader.
I've tested it too: with true or false it doesn't seem to change the outcome.

Comment: [`premultipliedAlpha`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.alpha) default is `true`! It matters. See [WebGL and Alpha](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-and-alpha.html)

Comment: I don't know the details of three.js implementation but naievely, if all it does is take the points and indices for an IcosahedronBufferGeometry and pass `gl.POINTS` instead of `gl.TRIANGLES` then every point is going to be drawn 5 times since every point is used by 5 triangles.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Aha! I thought you were referring to the `premultipliedAlpha` property of `Material` which defaults to false and, I believe, shouldn't influence CustomShaders that don't implement them... I will look into this resource and report back, thanks!

Comment: @gman, Oh wow, that would explain a lot. The error I'm seeing is sort of a multiple of 5... I'll start debugging that icosahedron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is every point is being drawn 5 times because `IcosahedronBufferGeometry` is designed for drawing triangles. Each vertex is shared by 5 triangles. We can test this by augmenting `drawArrays`

Running the code below we see it's asking to draw 60 points even though visually there would only be 12 (the code below does not draw anything visible, it's only designed to check the draw call).

```js
WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.drawArrays = function(origFn) {
  return function(...args) {
    console.log('drawArrays', ...args);
    origFn.call(this, ...args);
  };
}(WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.drawArrays);

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
  const camera = new THREE.Camera();
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const geo = new THREE.IcosahedronBufferGeometry(1);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
  scene.add(new THREE.Points(geo, material));
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r112/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the issue!